# Different Task approaches work differently

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I would like to ask why this two approaches are different and returns two different set of values:

The first one which is correct in my opinion return values from 0 to 8 and works on different threads (LINQPad code):

```
void Main()
{
    var newTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(x => Task.Run(() => DoSomething(x)));

    Task.WhenAll(newTasks);
}    

public int DoSomething(int value)
{
    return value;
}
```

Second, which is not correct in my opinion which returns random values a specially 9 but also works on different threads.

```
void Main()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    
    for (var index = 0; index < 9; index++)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => DoSomething(index));
        
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}    

public int DoSomething(int value)
{
    return value;
}
```

Is it possible to modify the second one and get the result similar to first example?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Related: [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to modify the second one and get the result similar to first example?

When you pass a variable or object into `Task.Run(()=> DoSomething(index))` you *capture* a variable.

In a sense you're not just sending that variable as a value or object, but giving that thread direct access to the original variable. (This is highly generalized and has lots of nuances).

The problem you most likely encountering is that the CLR is attempting to capture `index`, which is an *iterator* who's scope can not leave it's boundaries unless any attempt to do so would remain on the stack(the same thread basically, again over generalized).

When the CLR 'captures' `index` it will only capture a random value that `index` was(due to race conditions) - or the *last* value that `index` was, which is **double** un-intuitive because you explicitly told it that `index` should never get to `9` in this line here `for (var index = 0; index < 9; index++)`.

Here's the tricky thing, when the CLR captures `index`, it captures whatever the last value was for `index`. But after the loop ends `index` gets incremented one more time causing `9` to be the last value of `index`.

This can cause a whole host of problems, especially if you're working with arrays, here we come `IndexOutOfBoundsException`!

**How to fix it**
The fix is actually super simple! Just create a temporary variable in the loop, and pass that instead of `index` directly.

Here's an example:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    
    for (var index = 0; index < 9; index++)
    {
        int tmpIndex = index;

        var task = Task.Run(() => DoSomething(tmpIndex ));
        
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

> Is it possible to modify the second one and get the result similar to first example?

Side Note
*never rely on data from tasks to be in order, unless you explicitly implemented a guarantee that the items come back in order*. The `TaskScheduler` chooses `Tasks` to run normally in **FIFO**(first in first out), however, if the `TaskScheduler` optimizes, prioritizes, or shifts the tasks around(which is does frequently) your tasks will **not** complete in order and subsequently the results you get won't be in order.